# А есть ли русский вариант music.stackexchange.com?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

По адресам https://ru.music.stackoverflow.com ,  http://ru.music.stackexchange.com/ у меня 404, как ни странно)

Если нет, то планируется ли?

И как вообще осуществляется "заказ" создания тех или иных "веток" SO?

Comment: На ваш коммент на мой ответ: а где вы это сказали? Я ответил — Area 51. И почему вы вообще задумали спросить это здесь?

Comment: Банально, потому, что не знал где спрашивать :)