# Как понять логику участников меты?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов

У нас есть [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8339/%D0%90-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82-music-stackexchange-com) с заголовком "А есть ли русский вариант music.stackexchange.com?" Ну хорошо, дубликат, а почему не закрыт? Он же к теме сайта не относится, или я чего-то не понимаю? Или все на репутацию смотрят?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дубликат — автоматически подразумевает закрытие, то есть сайт блокирует возможность дать ответ на вопрос непосредственно на этой странице. Чтобы в этом убедиться, попробуйте поиск по опции [`closed:1`](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Closed%3A1).

По поводу онтопичности могу сказать следующее. На русском языке всего лишь два сайта сети Stack Exchange: [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) и «[Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/)». Какой-то общей меты, как это сделано для англоязычных сайтов, типа [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), нет. Поэтому подобные вопросы разрешено задавать на Мете ruSO.

Comment: А почему такие вопросы не задают на https://meta.stackexchange.com/? На английском?

Comment: @VerNick если бы все знали и предпочитали английский, не было бы ruSO.